# Using BundleConfig to Deliver jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js Results in 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have configured my BundleConfig to include the SignalR library as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/signalr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"));
```

I configured my page to request that bundle as follows:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalr")
```

When I run my application, I get a 404 from the HTTP request for /bundles/signalr.

I read some other SO threads around URL Routing with regard to the JS file having the extra period in the name.  I didn't have success with that.  Is that really the issue or is there something else I am missing?

All of my other bundles are working as expected.

Comment: Does it work when bundling & minification is off?

Comment: If you mean the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations flag?  I am not using it.  I assumed the default was false but I will run again with false explicitly set and check.

Comment: Default value is `false` in debug mode and `true` in release. When it's off, what does the generated `<script>` tag look like? Does that path exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo in the script src tag.